# how to stop an object when it collides with another object in javascript canvas

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

OK, so I am making a Pacman game using HTML5 . the problem is whenever I hit one of the brick blocks I want the sprite to stop moving but it keeps going until it hits the left most brick object.
how do I fix this? please help... here is the code I'm using to make the sprite stop.

here is all my code, if you have time, please parse it, and tell me what I have done wrong.

```
function init(){
    var canvas=document.getElementById("ctx");
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    var player = {sx:6,sy:6,sw:15,sh:15,x:230,y:377,w:20,h:20}
    var ss = new Image();
    ss.src="SS.png";
    var right=false,left= true,up = false,down = false
    var b = [{x:0,y:0,w:25,h:((canvas.height/2)-25)},{x:0,y:((canvas.height/2)),w:25,h:((canvas.height/2))},{x:50,y:25,w:50,h:50},{x:125,y:25,w:75,h:50},{x:225,y:0,w:25,h:75},{x:275,y:25,w:75,h:50},{x:375,y:25,w:50,h:50},{x:50,y:100,w:50,h:25},{x:125,y:100,w:25,h:125},{x:125,y:150,w:75,h:25},{x:175,y:100,w:125,h:25},{x:225,y:125,w:25,h:50},{x:325,y:100,w:25,h:125},{x:275,y:150,w:75,h:25},{x:375,y:100,w:50,h:25},{x:25,y:150,w:75,h:75},{x:375,y:150,w:75,h:75},{x:375,y:250,w:75,h:75},{x:25,y:250,w:75,h:75},{x:125,y:250,w:25,h:75},{x:325,y:250,w:25,h:75},{x:175,y:300,w:125,h:25},{x:225,y:325,w:25,h:50},{x:50,y:350,w:50,h:25},{x:75,y:350,w:25,h:75},{x:125,y:350,w:75,h:25},{x:275,y:350,w:75,h:25},{x:375,y:350,w:50,h:25},{x:375,y:350,w:25,h:75},{x:25,y:400,w:25,h:25},{x:125,y:400,w:25,h:75},{x:50,y:450,w:150,h:25},{x:275,y:450,w:150,h:25},{x:325,y:400,w:25,h:50},{x:425,y:400,w:25,h:25},{x:175,y:400,w:125,h:25},{x:225,y:425,w:25,h:50},{x:450,y:0,w:50,h:((canvas.height/2)-25)},{x:450,y:(canvas.height/2),w:50,h:((canvas.height/2))}];
    function gen(){
        for(var i=0;i<b.length;i++){
           ctx.fillStyle="blue"
           ctx.fillRect(b[i].x,b[i].y,b[i].w,b[i].h) 
        }
        ctx.drawImage(ss,player.sx,player.sy,player.sw,player.sh,player.x,player.y,player.w,player.h) 
    }
    function move(){
    for(var i=0;i<b.length;i++){
     //((a.x + a.width) < b.x)
        if(left &&
     player.x > b[i].x && (player.x + player.w) < (b[i].x + b[i].w) &&
player.y > b[i].y && (player.y + player.h) < (b[i].y + b[i].h)) {
    // here you can tell that the user is colliding an object
 player.x-=1

        }
        else {

        }
    }
    }
    function animate(){
     ctx.save()
     ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.width);
     gen()
     move()
     ctx.restore();   
    }
var ani = setInterval(animate, 30)
}
window.addEventListener("load",function(){
 init()   
})
```

Answer (score 2):

First, I can see a problem with the first part of your if condition:

```
left = true && ...
```

Should be

```
left === true && ...
```

Or even better

```
left && ...
```

Now for the collision part it usually is top-left or in the middle of the object

I'd suggest this top-left origin collision check:

```
if(left &&
   (player.x >= b[i].x && player.x + player.w <= b[i].x + b[i].w) &&
   (player.y >= b[i].y && player.y + player.h <= b[i].y + b[i].h) {
        // here you can tell that the user is colliding an object
    }
```

It checks several cases, this part

```
(player.x >= b[i].x && player.x + player.w <= b[i].x + b[i].w)
```

Will meet requirements if the player's x (with its width component) inside the occupied x range of the current object

The second part

```
(player.y >= b[i].y && player.y + player.h <= b[i].y + b[i].h)
```

Will meet requirements if the player's y (with its height component) is inside the occupied y range of the current object.

It will only execute the if statement if the condition is satisfied for both of the above cases.

You can tell if you should reposition the player on the left or on the right, by substracting the players x component to the object's x component, same goes for top or bottom with y component. The previous sentence is only valid if you move in a grid cell by cell.

Comment: ive tried your code, and it works... somewhat... the sprite wont move because evrey "corridor " of this game is 25x25 pixels and the sprite, logically, is 25x25 pixels so it touches the blocks above it and stops moving on spawn

Comment: You could transform the `>=` to `>` and `<=` to `<`

Comment: the sprite will still not move on spawn,

Comment: You should post some more code, or even open another question then (since it seems to be another problem)